# MS Office SharePoint Server 2007 UI language change

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

There is an existing app in MOSS, which allows to create polls for a call center, operators fill them out as they call targeted customers. Then this Web app outputs the results of this poll.
Is it possible to change the interface language of this existing web app? Operators don't understand English. If it's not about language packs, it would still be easier for me to embed new names and labels, rather than rewrite in a system I am not familiar with.

Also, is it possible to change the authentication type from Windows authentication to regular username/password check (username and password will be stored in DB or somewhere only for this site)

If it is possible, can you direct me to some kind of tutorial, help or manual which would show how to do it?

On MSDN it's written that language can't be changed, but I'm not sure whether it's about the Web app language.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at chapter 4 in our free [SharePoint Development Guidelines](http://www.muhimbi.com/blog/2009/05/muhimbis-sharepoint-development.html).

Answer (score 1):

I have no mutch idea about web app language

But I shall share you the links for sql authentication

http://weblog.vb-tech.com/nick/archive/2006/06/14/1617.aspx 
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/sharepoint/moss_enableforms.aspx

Answer (score 1):

For SharePoint it is possible to create different web's in different languages. Not that i know you could use one web in different languages.

But, it may be funny or not, a crazy idea or not, but could work: before dumping rendered contents to user, maybe you could extract text values excluding form values, post them to [Google](http://translate.google.com/#) or [Bing](http://www.microsofttranslator.com) translator and put back translated values? You can override [global.asax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178473.aspx) file and use PreSendRequestContent to modify contents just before they are sent to client.

If your company is not huge and it's an intranet page, then, althought slower, but it could work. Better than nothing.

> PreSendRequestContent. This event
>   signals that content is about to be
>   sent to the client. This provides an
>   opportunity to modify the content
>   before it is sent.